# PredExp vs Expression - Aerospike Client (list of integers)

Tags: java, expression, predicate, aerospike

What would be the Expression substitute for the below code which uses PredExp for aerospike client

```
predExps = Arrays.asList(PredExp.integerVar("v"), PredExp.integerValue((Long) fieldValue),       PredExp.integerEqual(), PredExp.listBin(fieldName), PredExp.listIterateOr("v"));
```

Not able to figure out how to replicate the list behaviour here.

Tried to replicate the same behaviour using Exp.intOr but that is not working

Comment: [`Exp.intOr`](https://docs.aerospike.com/server/guide/expressions/arithmetic#int_or) is a bitwise or operation.

Answer (score 3):

Your predexp is checking if any value in a list matches a particular value:

```java
predExps = Arrays.asList(
         PredExp.integerVar("v"),
         PredExp.integerValue((Long) fieldValue),
         PredExp.integerEqual(),
         PredExp.listBin(fieldName),
         PredExp.listIterateOr("v")
);
```

The equivalent in expression is to use the [`list_get_by_value()`](https://docs.aerospike.com/server/guide/expressions/bin-ops-list#list_get_by_value) expression. Should be similar to the following in Java - I'm currently unable to test:

```java
Exp.build(
    ListExp.getByValue(
        ListReturnType.EXISTS, Exp.val(fieldValue), Exp.listBin(fieldName)))
```

Comment: Hi, should it be ListReturnType.EXISTS or ListReturnType.VALUE ? Also what would the changes required to query a string value on a list of strings?

Comment: EXISTS will stop at the first match and return a boolean, which is probably what you want. I don't think any changes are required for string other than `fieldValue` would need to be a string.